# want to implement the desoslider in my website

Tags: osclass

my web site is using osclass classified script and i want to implement the desoslider in my website and i followed the [[http://sylouuu.github.io/desoslide/documentation.html#setup][1]](http://sylouuu.github.io/desoslide/documentation.html#setup%5d%5b1%5d) 
the code and script i have used is below

PHP

```php
 <?php if( osc_images_enabled_at_items() ) { ?>
                <?php if( osc_count_item_resources() > 0 ) { ?>
                <div id="photos">
                    <?php for ( $i = 0; osc_has_item_resources(); $i++ ) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo osc_resource_url(); ?>" rel="image_group" title="<?php _e('Image', 'modern'); ?> <?php echo $i+1;?> / <?php echo osc_count_item_resources();?>">
                        <?php if( $i == 0 ) { ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo osc_resource_url(); ?>" width="70" height="50" alt="<?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>" />
                        <?php } else { ?>
                       <img  src="<?php echo osc_resource_thumbnail_url(); ?>" width="70" height="50" alt="<?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo osc_item_title(); ?>" />
                        <?php } ?>
                    </a>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
                  <div id=demo></div>
```

JS

```js
$(function() {
    $('#photos').desoSlide({
        main: {
            container: '#demo',
            cssClass: 'img-responsive'
        },
        caption: true
    });
});
```

the document says that we have to specify your images links and the alt attribute. i tried several steps but no success. help me to successfully use this desoslider

Comment: Hi, take a look about the version 2 http://sylouuu.github.io/desoslide/

Answer (score 2):

Because in 1.* versions your thumbnails must be inside an `<ul>` tag with `<li>`. So replace `<div id="photos">` by `<ul id="photos">` and wrap `<a>` within `<li>`.

But anyway, this mandatory markup structure has been changed, the version 2 is more permissive. Check it out: http://sylouuu.github.io/desoslide/doc/